# Wiring connections for cooktop range

Tags: wiring

I have a power source with black, white and bare wires.  My cook top has black, white, green and red wires.  After connecting black to black and white to white, not sure what to do with the bare wire coming from the power source and the green and red wires on the cook top.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was in the place of the cooktop?  What country are you in?  Is this a standard 30" cooktop or a smaller type?

Comment: Assuming you're in the US, is your power source 120v with a neutral or 240v with two hots? If the latter, white to white is very likely wrong and could result in electrocution, do not turn on the breaker until you know it's not hot.

Answer (score 4):

If the feed only has two wires (not including ground), it's possible that it's only 120 volts (hot, neutral, ground) or 240 volts (hot, hot, ground). If there's only a single pole breaker, then it's probably 120 volts. If there's a double pole breaker, it's probably 240 volts. You can measure it of course, if you have a volt/multimeter.

Since the new cooktop has an additional wire, I'd suspect that it requires a 120/240 volt feed (hot, hot, neutral, ground). This means that you're going to have to pull a new three wire with ground cable, or an additional wire if it's wired through conduit.

If the feed is 240 volts (hot, hot, ground), and you've connected the new cooktop as described (black to black, white to white). You've potentially connected an ungrounded (hot) conductor from the feed, to the grounded (neutral) conductor of the cooktop. This is very bad, and could kill somebody.

Contact a local licensed Electrician, or do some more research before continuing with this project.